# Roots of polynomial $-4x^3+3x^2-2x+1=0$

Tags: polynomials

I've calculated the derivative of the function $f(x)=-4x^3+3x^2-2x+1$ and came up with $f'(x)=-12x^2+6x-2$ which is always negative and since $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x)=\infty$ I assumed that $f(x)=0$ has only one real solution and two other complex ones.
But I'm confused since the polynomial has integer coefficients, shouldn't there be a way to determine the real solution?

Comment: No one says there isn't a way to determine the real solution...

Comment: http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+4x%5E3-3x%5E2%2B2x-1&x=9&y=13 It's ugly, but it's there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about the polynomial $f$ having only one real root. Since $f'$ is always negative $f$ is strictly decreasing ...

To find the root you can use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_of_roots) formula.